# CSS image is not covering whole screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like my css image to cover the whole screen, I am randomly choosing an image from a JS array. It is showing the image, but is not showing a Perfect Full Page Background Image.

**main.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<button id = "button1">Click</button>


    <script src = "main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
      showImage();
    });
    ...
    function showImage(){
    document.write('<img class = "bg" src="'+theImages[whichImage]+'">');
    }
```

**main.css**

```
img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%; 
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to add an `<img>` as an element? If you just want a background image, why not use the css `[background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)` property, perhaps on the `<body>`? Then you can just set `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: 100%;` to get what you want.

Comment: @neilsimp I don't think that would work for me because I'm randomly selecting an image from an array of images for the background.

Comment: `document.body.style['background-image'] = 'url("' + theImages[whichImage] + '")';` would set that property.

Comment: @neilsimp1 ok, I'm using your method. It is completely covering my page now, but is showing it clearly. I would like the width to be 100% and height to be auto and hide the overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of css is that? I don't recommend using vw/vh either.

You'd be best off using standard background sizes and positions like

```
/*background-image: url(../images/background.png);*/ optional
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
```

and you could always add

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

for total cross-browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I agree that setting the `document.body.style['background-image']` attribute would be the best way to go, especially since it allows you to cope with the image shape not matching the screen shape (fix using `background-position` and `background-size`). If you still want to use an `<img>`, you can use the CSS3 length units `vh`, `vw`. Support for modern browsers can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

```
img.bg {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Notice the image will not become higher than the view-port, even if the `body` element does (i.e. there is a scroll-bar).